# Combining Columns into One Table in SQl

Tags: sql

I have two tables (Table 1 and Table 2) that include information on a company's insurance policies. There are thousands of rows and around 30 columns in each table. I need to create a table that combines certain columns from each table into a new table.

```
From Table 1 I need: 
InvestmentCode, IndexType, Amount, FundID, PolicyNumber

From Table 2 I need: 
PolicyNumber, FundValue, DepositDate, FundID
```

I want to merge the tables by FundID and Policynumber

Comment: Don't copy data from one table to another. Create a view instead.

Comment: Hint: You want a basic `JOIN`.

Comment: Provide some sample data with expected output

Comment: If you _want to merge the tables by FundID and Policynumber_, doesn't that mean that the FundID and the Policynumber is the same in both Table 1 and Table 2? So why would you need those values from both tables? You only need them from one of the tables, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually creating one more table would be data redundancy (because you already have data present and you are just copying) ,

you can always create view for this , for your query - view will be something as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <view_name>  AS

select T1.InvestmentCode , T1.IndexType , T1.Amount , T1.FundID , T1.PolicyNumber , 
            T2.FundValue , T2.DepositDate  from Table1 T1 , Table2 T2 
        where  T1.FundID = T22.FundID 
        and T2.PolicyNumber = T2.PolicyNumber

WITH READ ONLY
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Yes - @jarlh , indeed ! that was just to show the user , thank you for pointing that out